# Generating a regular expression from a language

Tags: regex, regular-language, lexical-analysis, dfa, nfa

I need to find a regular expression to define the language of **all binary strings  with at most one 1 in each substring of length four**.

**Accepted string: 0001000100**

**Rejected string: 100010100**

My current attempt is: **((0*)(1){0,1}(0*)){4}**. Though per various regex-testing sites that is incorrect, something I don't find surprising as I'm new to regular expressions.

I believe this language to be regular and as such I am asked to find a regular expression to define it, along with and NFA and DFA, the process for each I am okay with. However, I am struggling to come up with a regular expression that defines the language.

Comment: Depending on the context in which you need to solve this problem, you could use something like `/11/101/1001/g` to match all of the binary strings that **don't** satisfy your requirements, and then filter those out to be left with the binary strings that you do want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex seems to define the language you want, where no two 1's will be present within four characters,

```
^0*(?:10{3,})*1?0*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `0*` - One or more zeroes
- `(?:10{3,})*` - This matches a literal `1` then at least three or more zeroes and whole of it zero or more times
- `1?0*` - Optionally follows a literal `1` and then zero or more zeroes
- `$` - End of string

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lPdMK6/1)**

Comment: That's great, thank you! I'm not familiar with the use of the colon, though by limited 'research' it looks like it's pattern clustering? Does that then imply that ?:01 could be read as one or more instances of the string '01'?

Comment: @kbur36: Use of `?:` before a `(` makes the group as non-capture group and doesn't affect it matching wise at all. If you want, you can remove `?:` from the regex and it will continue to work like I described. Let me know if my solution works for you. In case it works, please consider marking it as accepted answer by clicking the tick mark against the answer which would also give you additional reputation as well as help future SO users in case they come looking for similar question.